# Build Environment C++ using Mingw?

Tags: c++, build, environment

I haven't programmed for a while and am trying to set up my build environment on a new laptop.  I've just forgotten how and think that I did allot of things wrong last time!

What I'm trying to do is have that common Include Directory and common Lib directory so when I build projects or other dependencies, etc... my compiler is able to find all the include and lib files it needs.  I'm not formally trained so some obvious things to you guys are learning points for me.

I'm going to use a Mingw compiler and MSYS.   Off memory I put the Include directory and the lib directory in the Mingw directory but I could be wrong there.

I'm just trying to set up an effective and simple build environment on Windows 7.

Where should all my directories go?    Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with /usr/include and /usr/lib?

Comment: Thanks for responding.. I'm just piecing this together in my head, but I gather you're referring to the default search path.  Is that correct?  user as in the 'user' directory in Windows 7.   I didn't see the 'User' directory in Win XP but that was still a default search path.  That's a little confusing.

Comment: Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't already, MSYS2 is generally preferred over MSYS. I'm going to answer this assuming MSYS2. I use the 64 bit version, so that is what I'll show, but it should be simple enough to change.

I will also assume you put the `msys64` directory in the base directory, if not replace `C:/msys64/` with `C:/wherever/you/put/it/msys64/`.

When using the msys shell, `/c/msys64/usr/` is the same as `C:/msys64/usr/` which is the same as `/usr/` since it tries to blend Linux file organization with windows, and it can sometimes be slightly unintuitive. When you install msys libraries, usually the include files are in `C:/msys64/usr/include/` and the libraries are in `C:/msys64/usr/lib/`. The exception to this is when you have a 64-bit version and a 32-bit version of a program, in which case the headers are in `C:/msys64/mingw64/include/` and the libs in `C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/` for 64-bit (`mingw32` for 32 bit).

In order to build using these, you will need to add the appropriate include paths and library paths. So, to make all 64-bit programs available, you would add the following flags

```
-IC:/msys64/usr/include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include -LC:/msys64/usr/lib -LC:/msys64/mingw64/lib
```

When you compile your own programs from source, you put them wherever you'd like. It is best not to put them in the same directory as the package manager to avoid collisions. Running `make install` sometimes won't run as seamlessly on msys as it would on linux. In these cases, creating a folder such as `C:/msys64/custom/include/` is a safer alternative. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30/where-should-i-put-software-i-compile-myself for some more insight on this.

Comment: Thanks very much for that.  Great explanation!

Comment: Can I just ask, in relation to above, do I put my compiler in the mingw64 and mingw32 directories in the MSYS directory?  I see there are two empty folders in the MSYS directory with mingw64 and mingw32 labels.    Is there any advantage to doing this, or is it only important that wherever I put my compiler that it's bin directory is in the 'PATH' environmental variable?

Comment: @simonyin what exactly do you mean by "put your compiler in" the directory? They are installed in the usr/bin folder by default (as are all executables installed with the package manager).

Comment: I'm on Windows 7.